# How to return static file in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a laravel-project where my root should return static html (it's an ajax app).

I concider putting my static html in the public-folder and then use routes to return it. Is this a good approach? If so, how do I return a file in php?

Answer (score 4):

You can use static HTML code inside of Laravel views without any difficulties. No need to put them elsewhere. This way you will still be able to use all the convenient automatic routing and linking functions that make Laravel 4 so awesome.

Separating static and dynamic pages would make no sense at all. You might want to insert dynamic content in a static page later on, for example, so it's better not to separate them.
And even if they remain static, why give up the possibility to modularize pages using Blade?

Comment: Separating static and dynamic pages does make sense if you're building a standalone application...